# Resize css image to fit

Tags: html, css

So im putting list of types and each one has an image. As you can see the list below has the water image cut.  How can I fix this?

I have a class for the water text so it can display the text and im trying to add it to a html list.

this is my class code in css

```
.water{
    background: url('../images/water.png');
    object-fit: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

[image]

This worked thanks to HolyMoly

"object-fit is used directly on img tags to my understanding, I think you want background-size: contain or background-size: cover since you are not applying the css to an image tag, rather using the image as a background" – HolyMoly

Comment: Please provide some code example, we wouldn't be able to help you with just an image

Comment: @DineiRockenbach Added

Comment: Your `.water` class says that it fits the size of the parent element. You didn't provide HTML structure nor CSS for the parent element. We need a full example.

Comment: `object-fit` is used directly on `img` tags to my understanding, I think you want `background-size: contain` or `background-size: cover` since you are not applying the css to an image tag, rather using the image as a background

Answer (score 0):

kindly check background-size:contain or background: url('../images/water.png') 50px 50px;
directly mention you size of image